# Creating a link in top menu in Magento

Tags: magento, menu

Hi I hope you can help me with this. I'm new in Magento and I'm trying to implement the same functionality discussed in this thread

[Magento hide navigation menu item from guest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712517/magento-hide-navigation-menu-item-from-guest/22550519#22550519).

The only thing I haven't figured out yet is how to create a navigation block in the first place or create custom links in the top menu.

I have been trying to follow the method described in the link below but I'm not sure which config.xml and observer file I should modify in order to get this work

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/adding-links-to-the-top-menu-in-magento/comment-page-1/#comment-71252

Could somebody please provides me with some guidance?

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? you want a menu that should show up when user login?

Comment: @Luis_DV what Menu and content you want to add?
Like Product Category or Else?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understand by your question here [Magento hide navigation menu item from guest.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712517/magento-hide-navigation-menu-item-from-guest/22550519#22550519)

so you need to follow the steps

step 1: Need to create observer by using event page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before

you will find lots of article to create an observer as you added

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/adding-links-to-the-top-menu-in-magento/comment-page-1/

and update the code with below

```
    $subNode = new Varien_Data_Tree_Node($data, 'id', $tree, $node);
    // here added the condition to check the customer is logged in or not then only show the menu
    if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
    {
       $node->addChild($subNode);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. I assumes that, you want to add new menu in header  and you want to show it only when user is logged in. Based on that assumption, let us start to create a `custom module`. (Tutorial that you point out is referencing your own module and not to any other existing module). Let us create a module with name `Mysite_Addmenu`

First you need to configure your module. For that create a file in

Location : `app/code/core/local/Mysite/Addmenu/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Mysite_Addmenu>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mysite_Addmenu>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <events>
      <page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before>
          <observers>
              <add_top_menu>
                  <type>singleton</type>
                  <class>addmenu/observer</class>
                  <method>addToTopmenu</method>
              </add_top_menu>
          </observers>
      </page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before>
    </events>   
</frontend>
<global>
    <models>
        <addmenu>
            <class>Mysite_Addmenu_Model</class>
        </addmenu>
    </models>
</global>
</config>
```

As you can see it has two section. One section defines the observer part and other section defines its model part. In model, you are going to define your observer.

Now let us make magento knows about our module.For this you need to add this file in the given location

Location:`app/etc/modules/Mysite_Addmenu.xml`

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Mysite_Addmenu>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Mysite_Addmenu>
</modules>
</config>
```

Now its time to define our observer.Let us do that

Location : app/code/local/Mysite/Addmenu/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class Mysite_Addmenu_Model_Observer
{

    public function addToTopmenu(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
        {
            $menu = $observer->getMenu();
            $tree = $menu->getTree();
            $node = new Varien_Data_Tree_Node(array(
                    'name'   => 'Newmenu',
                    'id'     => 'newmenu',
                    'url'    => Mage::getUrl().'newmenu', // point somewhere
            ), 'id', $tree, $menu);
            $menu->addChild($node);
            // Children menu items
            $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
                    ->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
                    ->addIsActiveFilter()
                    ->addNameToResult()
                    ->setPageSize(3);
            foreach ($collection as $category) {
                $tree = $node->getTree();
                $data = array(
                    'name'   => $category->getName(),
                    'id'     => 'category-node-'.$category->getId(),
                    'url'    => $category->getUrl(),
                );
                $subNode = new Varien_Data_Tree_Node($data, 'id', $tree, $node);
                $node->addChild($subNode);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

**What observer does :** Observer checks whether a user is exist or not. If not, it will not create a menu. If a user is already logged in, then the menu will appear.

I have used same code in referenced tutorial. You can make your own changes to  submenu part. Display it as you desire. Hope it will help you.